# HP 630 Laptop Overheats and Shuts down

Tags: laptop, cpu, shutdown, cooling, overheating

My laptop overheats and shuts itself down while playing games on it. The fans starts to spin very fast and within a minute it goes of. After restarting, it givers me thermal overheating message (but not every time). So I thought it will be problem of CPU cooling system.

Therefore I opened it up, cleaned it as much as possible, cleaned the old thermal paste with isopropyl alcohol and replaced it with new one (**arctic silver 5**). Even after doing so the problem remains the same.

This problem doesn't occur with very old games like CS 1.6, but if I play games like any version of Call of Duty, IGI 1-2 etc. it goes off.

One thing to notice is that the area where the CPU is install on motherboard gets warm before shutting down. I saw my friends laptop which emits similar amount of heat from exhaust fan while playing games, but his CPU portion remains cool.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the fans are all working properly?  Its possible the fan may be having some trouble.

Comment: Yes I did. It is working fine. When I cleaned my laptop, for first few days, it took more time for it to shut down compare to previous, before cleaning.